# Google play developer console shows DS_Store in Native Platforms section of uploaded Apk

Tags: android, macos, build, apk

Native platforms field shows: .DS_Store, armeabi-v7a
on play store developer dashboard when I upload my newly built Apk file.

How can I remove & ignore .DS_Store files from Android build system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when you play a lot with the Finder of Mac OSX in the directories of Android Project.

You need to close Finder and remove these files (named .DS_Store) from console with "rm".