# Android app shows as not compatible with any device

Tags: android

I am going out of my mind... I tried changing the uses-feature camera to false, remove it, remove all permissions... It keeps saying that is compatible with 0 devices... Sdks are min 16 target 21.... What am I missing?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- Application Metadata -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="*********************************" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="*********************************" />

    <!-- Login Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Register Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly.LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Main Activity (Drawer) -->
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>

    <!-- View Picture Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".ViewPictureActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_view_picture"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Settings Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly.MainActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- Facebook Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".FacebookActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_facebook" >
    </activity>

    <!-- Twitter Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name=".TwitterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_twitter" >
    </activity>



</application>
```

build.gradle **<--- The solution is in this file!**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 2
    versionName '1.0.1'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'  <!-- Replace this with 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4' -->
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

aapt dump badging

```
package: name='com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly' versionCode='2' versionName='1.0.1' platformBuildVersionName='5.0.1-1624448'
sdkVersion:'16'
targetSdkVersion:'21'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.CAMERA'
application-label:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ca:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-da:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-fa:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ja:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-pa:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ta:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-nb:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-de:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-he:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-te:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-af:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-bg:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-th:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-fi:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-hi:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-vi:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-sk:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-uk:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-el:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ml:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-nl:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-pl:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-sl:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-tl:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-am:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-bn:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-in:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-kn:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ko:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ro:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ar:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-fr:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-hr:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-mr:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-sr:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-tr:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ur:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-cs:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-es:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ms:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-it:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-lt:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-pt:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-gu:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-hu:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ru:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-zu:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-lv:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-sv:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-iw:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-sw:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-fr-CA:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-lo-LA:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-en-GB:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-bn-BD:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-et-EE:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ka-GE:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ky-KG:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-km-KH:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-zh-HK:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-si-LK:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-mk-MK:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ur-PK:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-hy-AM:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-my-MM:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-zh-CN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ta-IN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-te-IN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ml-IN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-en-IN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-kn-IN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-mr-IN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-mn-MN:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ne-NP:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-gl-ES:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-es-ES:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-eu-ES:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-is-IS:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-en-SS:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-es-US:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-pt-PT:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-zh-TW:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-en-XX:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-ms-MY:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-kk-KZ:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-label-uz-UZ:'Chefs Eyes Only'
application-icon-160:'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-213:'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-240:'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-320:'res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-480:'res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application-icon-640:'res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
application: label='Chefs Eyes Only' icon='res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.twentythreepixels.chefseyesonly.LoginActivity'  label='Chefs Eyes Only' icon=''
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-implied-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' reason='requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'pa' 'ta' 'nb' 'de' 'he' 'te' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'fi' 'hi' 'vi' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'ml' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am' 'bn' 'in' 'kn' 'ko' 'ro' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'mr' 'sr' 'tr' 'ur' 'cs' 'es' 'ms' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'gu' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv'
 'iw' 'sw' 'fr-CA' 'lo-LA' 'en-GB' 'bn-BD' 'et-EE' 'ka-GE' 'ky-KG' 'km-KH' 'zh-HK' 'si-LK' 'mk-MK' 'ur-PK' 'hy-AM' 'my-MM' 'zh-CN' 'ta-IN' 'te-IN' 'ml-IN' 'en-IN' 'kn-IN' 'mr-IN' 'mn-MN' 'ne-NP' 'gl-ES' 'es-ES' 'eu-ES' 'is-IS' 'en-SS' 'es-US' 'pt-PT' 'zh-TW' 'e
n-XX' 'ms-MY' 'kk-KZ' 'uz-UZ'
densities: '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640'
native-code: 'lib/commons-io-2.4.jar'
```

Comment: It always did or is it since a recent update? If so, what changed in the AndroidManifest?

Comment: It always did... I published the app yesterday and when I could not find it in the play store I checked and it said Devices Supported 0... I tried following a bunch of solutions changing stuff around, I even created a whole new project and moved all the code, rebuilt dependencies and repackaged the apk just in case there was any conflict... Nothing every time I upload a new version to see if anything changes it keeps saying 0 in the preview...

Comment: Oh btw... I am using apache.commons.io and it shows commons-io-2.4.jar as Native platform in the developer console...

Comment: I don't see the uses-sdk tag in your manifest. Are you using android studio? Post your build.gradle

Comment: Run 'aapt dump badging' from a command line... what does it show?

Comment: Ok I ran it... And updated the question.

Comment: The problems seems to be in the dependency org.apache.commons.io:2.4... When I remove the dependency the app is available to 6000+ devices.... Except that without that it doesn't work. Am I importing it wrong? I did it from Project Structure > Dependencies... And the app works on my devices..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK... So I finally found the solution... Thanks to this question [Google Play "Native platforms" showing commons-io-2.4.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750138/google-play-native-platforms-showing-commons-io-2-4-jar)

When I realized that it was dependent on apache.commons.io I looked for a solution... and I actually fixed it following the instructions of @Pang replacing `'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'` with `'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'` compiled... and boom! compatible with 6000 devices and change...

Thanks to everyone!